# mysql remove all hyphens and whitespaces

Tags: mysql, replace

How to remove all dashes and white space in column **interchange** below in red
I already used **REPLACE** `replace(coretable.interchange, '-', ''))` only (-) dash, but how about whitespace.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple replace should work

This replaces itphen('-') with empty spaces

```
UPDATE `coretable` SET `interchange` = REPLACE(`interchange`, '-', '');
```

This replaces space(' ') with empty spaces

```
UPDATE `coretable` SET `interchange` = REPLACE(`interchange`, ' ', '');
```

if you want just to view, but not update - u can use a double replace

```
select REPLACE(REPLACE(`interchange`, '-', ''), ' ', '') from coretable;
```